# Entity и Value object на основе одного класса

Tags: c#, entity, dto

Скажите, пожалуйста, в рамках подхода `DDD`, является ли корректным рассматривать один и тот же класс как `Entity` и как `Value object`.

Например, есть объект `Book` с набором свойств. Книга принадлежит владельцу. Я не хочу каждый раз при изменении информации о книге пересоздавать объект `Book` в `Owner`.

В классе `Owner` содержится приватное поле `_userBook` типа `IBook`, представляющее собой `Entity`. Свойство `UserBook (Value object)` используется для получения информации о книге владельца. Оно возвращает `IBookValue`.

В одном случае мне необходимо изменить параметр сущности, в другом случае просто получить информацию о книге без возможности ее изменения.

Насколько корректен данный подход?

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        BookDTO book = new BookDTO() {
            Name = "Ведьмак",
            Price = 1500
        };

        Owner user = new Owner(book);

        book.Price = 2000;

        user.UpdateBookInfo(book);
    }
}

// Библиотека
public class Owner : IOwner {
    private IBook _userBook;

    public Owner(IBookValue bookInfo) {
        _book = new Book(bookInfo);
    }

    public IBookValue UserBook{ 
        get { return _userBook; }
    }

    public void UpdateBookInfo(IBookValue bookInfo) {
        _userBook.Update(bookInfo);
    }
}

// Книга
public class Book : IBook {
    public Book(IBookValue bookInfo) {
        Update(bookInfo);
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public double Price { get; private set; }

    public void Update(IBookValue bookInfo) {
        Name = bookInfo.Name;
        Price = bookInfo.Price;
    }

}

// Информационно-транспортный объект для сериализации, вывода информации о книге и т. д.
public class BookDTO : IBookValue {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double Price { get; set; }   
}

// Информация о книге

public interface IBookValue {
    string Name { get; }

    double Price { get; }
}

// Сущность книги
public interface IBook : IBookValue {
    void Update(IBookValue bookInfo);
}


// Информация о владельце книги  
public interface IOwnerValue {
    IBookValue UserBook{ get; }
}

// Владелец книги  
public interface IOwner : IOwnerValue {
    void UpdateBookInfo(IBookValue bookInfo);
}

// Информационно-транспортный объект для сериализации, вывода информации о владельце и т. д.
public class OwnerDTO : IOwnerValue {
    public IBookValue Book { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: Я не спец, но, насколько я помню, если вы не хотите менять объект - то это обычной рид однли объект. ValueObject - это то, что менять в принципе не нужно, а можно просто старое значение выкинуть и засунуть новое. Отсюда и Value в названии, что оно либо меняется полностью, либо не меняется, как единое целое Value.

Comment: Igor Sergeevich, спасибо за ответ). Однако ValueObject хранит только набор значений. Entity предусматривает наличие правил валидации. Поэтому я не могу просто взять и подать на вход UpdateBookInfo IBookValue с простым набором значений. Валидацию я хочу сохранить внутри модели, а именно в IBook.

Comment: Подозреваю, что если вы валидируете ValueObject, то это вроде уже не ValueObject. Но я могу ошибаться, конечно, давно с DDD не работал :)

Answer (score 0):

Рассматривать один и тот же объект как `Entity` и `Value object` некорректно из-за принципиальных различий.
`Entity` имеет идентичность и жизненный цикл, тогда как `Value object` это только характеристика `Entity`.

Нет ничего плохого в измении характерискик `Entity`, цены в вашем случае. И для этого совершенно не нужно создавать новую сущность.
Если вы хотите получить представление объекта для целей транспортировки, то добавьте соответствующий метод `ToDto()` в книгу, который вернет необходимый набор характеристик.

Кстати, не стоит создавать интерфейсы для доменных объектов, как минимум, пока вам не понадобится от них полиморфное поведение.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Однако меня мучает следующий вопрос: взаимодействие с сущностями агрегата должно происходить исключительно через методы агрегата. Поэтому и было создано 2 интерфейса. С одной стороны приватным объектом является сущность - книга. С другой стороны, чтобы пользователь не мог воспользоваться методами обновления непосредственно книги (условно Owner.Book.Update()), было создано публичное свойство UserBook, которое возвращало сущность книги, завернутую в интерфейс объекта значения IBookValue. Иного способа защитить методы сущности книги от непосредственного использования я не знаю.

Comment: В Интернете на форуме по ddd поднимался такой вопрос. Но толкового ответа никто дать не смог. Предлагалось относиться к использованию методов дочерних сущностей через методы агрегата как к рекомендации и не беспокоиться об их защите от непосредственного использования.  Но я не согласен с такой точкой зрения. Интерфейсы я использую для будущего юнит-тестирования. Да и удобно в целом, посмотрев на интерфейс, увидеть суть класса.

Comment: Когда вы говорите что " взаимодействие с сущностями агрегата должно происходить исключительно через методы агрегата." это не означает буквально что нельзя изменить данные в книге через саму книгу. Это означает, что получить доступ к объекту книге можно только через корень агрегата. Изменения через корень агрегата необходимы когда можно нарушить консистентность этого агрегата изменив одно значение но забыв изменить другое. Если в данном случае консистентность нарушить нельзя, то не надо нагружать интерфейс корня дополнительными методами.

Comment: И проблема, которую я не могу понять, это от кого вы пытаетесь защищитить доменную модель?

Comment: Откуда, кстати, цитата  " взаимодействие с сущностями агрегата должно происходить исключительно через методы агрегата." ?

Comment: Про взаимодействие с сущностями агрегата взято из книги Эрика Эванса "Предметно-ориентирвоанное проектирвоание" на странице 128: " Осуществляйте все обращения к объектам в границах АГРЕГАТА только через его корневой объект."
Допустим, у меня есть класс AllUsers, инкапсулирующий в себя список всех пользователей. Пусть у нескольких пользователей есть одна и та же книга. Пусть у этой книги поменялась цена. Тогда для всех пользователей я могу поменять книгу условно так AllUsers.ChangeBookPrice(string bookName, double price).

Comment: Однако если у меня будет непосредственный доступ к каждому пользователю в AllUsers, то мне ничего не будет стоить изменить цену книги отдельного пользователя. User.ChangeBookPrice(string bookName, double price). При этом у остальных пользователей, владеющих указанной книгой останется прежняя цена. Что будет некорректно. Поэтому я и стремлюсь взаимодействовать с объектами исключительно через агрегат.
Однако меня волнует то, что в таком случае агрегат рискует стать God-сущностью. Слишком много будет в нем методов, слишком тяжелым он станет, что само по себе плохо.

Comment: Это обсуждение рискует вылиться в много страничный диалог, что не очень подходит для этого сайта. Однако отвечая на ваш вопрос, вы трактуете контроль доступа в стиле [LoD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) но из описания того же Еванса этого не следует, клиенты вполне могут взаимодействовать с книгой на прямую, только получая ее через корень агрегата, при условии что консистентность агрегата нарушена не будет.

Comment: То что у вас агрегат содержит всех пользователей, уже выглядит подозрительно. Вы будете вытягивать их в память только для того чтобы узнать чем владеет один из них? В чем смысл существования такого агрегата? Судя по вашим вопросам, вы не очень понимаете саму концепцию агрегатов, вам нужен более фундаментальный источник. Очень рекомендую ознакомится с [другими](https://www.amazon.com/Implementing-Domain-Driven-Design-Vaughn-Vernon/dp/0321834577) [авторами](https://www.amazon.com/Patterns-Principles-Practices-Domain-Driven-Design/dp/1118714709/) пишущими о DDD.

Comment: Да, я уже понял, что не совсем верно их понял. Сейчас смотрю в сторону хранения в агрегате идентификаторов дочерних сущностей и использования репозиториев. Насколько я понял, именно они нужны для поиска интересующих пользователей и книг (например по id, хотя некоторые авторы советуют использовать id по минимуму в сущностях)